# How to remove lines from a file where there are fewer than 5 and more than 10 characters inside parenthesis in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a file like this, containing pairs of `(` and `)` on each line:

```
This is a sentence (1).
This is another sentence (a note).
This is a sentence (2).
This is another sentence (with another, longer note).
```

I need to delete any lines in which there are fewer than 5 characters between the `(` and `)` and all lines in which there are more than 10 characters between the `(` and `)`. The output of the above sample would look like this:

```
This is another sentence (a note).
```

- There is never more than one set of parenthesis per line.
- The sets of parenthesis are never broken across lines.
- Any symbol, including spaces, inside the parenthesis can be counted as a character.

These are what I've have so far:

```
grep \([\w{5},\w{10}]\) file.txt

awk -F\( -F\) 'length($2)>5' 'length($2)<10' file.txt
```

How can I delete any lines from the file which have too few or too many characters inside the parenthesis?

Comment: I don't understand your example output. Shouldn't lines 1, 3, and 4 be removed from the output?

Answer (score 3):

This will keep all lines with 5-10 characters between the parentheses, and delete all other lines.

```
egrep '\(.{5,10}\)' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed '/(.\{10,\})\|(.\{,5\})/d' file.txt

sed -n '/(.\{5,10\})/p' file.txt
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# sed '/(.\{10,\})\|(.\{,5\})/d' file.txt
This is another sentence (a note).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
grep -P "\(.{5,10}\)" filename.txt
```

If you would like to set the results to a variable then you can use this.

```
var=$( grep -P "\(.{5,10}\)" filename.txt )
```

or

```
var=` grep -P "\(.{5,10}\)" filename.txt `
```

You should note that on the second example, it is using backticks not single quotes.
And if you are wanting to print the output to a file then you can use either

```
grep -P "\(.{5,10}\)" filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

or

```
grep -P "\(.{5,10}\)" filename.txt >> newfile.txt
```

Where the second example will add to an existing file or create a new file if needed.

you can also use egrep instead of grep (if you do then you don't nee the -P options

What this is doing is using a regular expression search thought he file and programs grep and egrep will print each line matching the regular expression provided. In this case the regular expression is `"\(.{5,10}\)"` The backslash means the next character is a literal character so when followed by a ( or a ) then you are saying a literal '(' and not what it would normally represent in a regular expression. the '.' means any character except newlines the {} indicate a limited number of repeats of the last character (in this case that would be any character) and the numbers inside are min and max, separated by a comma.

So were basically saying grep print out any line that has a string containing the pattern of open parenthesis then 5 to 10 characters that are not newline followed by a close parenthesis.

You can get more information on regex string here
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk. Five to ten characters between parenthesis

```
awk  '/\(.{5,10}\)/'  filename.txt
```

or five to ten non-right-paranthesis after a left parenthesis

```
awk  '/\([^)]{5,10}\)/'  filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign two field separators like that. Modifying your `awk` solution:

```
awk -F"[()]" 'length($2)>5 && length($2)<10’ file.txt
```